# Modifying the javascript array and pushing it into array is copying to every element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am not able to understand why it is copying the modified value to every element in the javascript array. Can somebody please explain the concept why?

```
var obj = {x:12};

var arr =[];

for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    obj["x"] = i;
    arr.push(obj);
    println("Inside -> " + JSON.stringify(arr));
}
println("Output -> " + JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Output of the above code returns -

```
Inside -> [{"x":0}]
Inside -> [{"x":1},{"x":1}]
Inside -> [{"x":2},{"x":2},{"x":2}]
Inside -> [{"x":3},{"x":3},{"x":3},{"x":3}]
Inside -> [{"x":4},{"x":4},{"x":4},{"x":4},{"x":4}]


Output -> [{"x":4},{"x":4},{"x":4},{"x":4},{"x":4}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing an reference of the original Object into the array.
By changing the value of an reference-object you do it for the original one too.

To prevent that you have to clone it.

```
const clone = Object.assign({}, obj)
```

Example:

```js
var obj = {
  x: 12
};

var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const clone = Object.assign({}, obj);
  clone["x"] = i;
  arr.push(clone);
  println("Inside -> " + JSON.stringify(arr));
}
println("Output -> " + JSON.stringify(arr));

function println(x) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

[Object.assign (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're pushing a reference to `obj` so whenever you make a `push` using the same object you basically duplicate the instance of it, also when you change 1 instance all of them will change value:

Imagine you have object `A` what you're doing is ...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  A = i;
  arr.push(A);
}
```

So you will push a total of 5 equal object instances and when you change 1 all of them will change value, instead you should use an approach like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  arr.push({ x: i });
}
```

So every time you will create a new object and the result will be:

`[{x:1},{x:2},{x:3},{x:4},{x:5}]`

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are pushing the same object to all indices in array. You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy an object and push a copy each to each index.

```js
var obj = {x:12};

var arr =[];

for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    let objCopy = Object.assign({}, obj);
    objCopy["x"] = i;
    arr.push(objCopy);
    console.log("Inside -> " + JSON.stringify(arr));
}
console.log("Output -> " + JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: You can also update x when you assign - `const objCopy = Object.assign({}, obj, { x: i });`

Comment: @OriDrori yes sure, useful in most real-life cases, I thought it didn't make much sense in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Complex values (i.e objects) are passed by *reference*.

In each iteration, you're simply working with the same object.
When you modify it, the modification reflects to all the passed references already present in your `arr`

```js
var foo = { foo: 'bar' }

// you assume we are gonna copy the value of `foo` to `foo2` 
var foo2 = foo

// change the value of the original object
foo.foo = 'baz'

// the change reflects to the other object,
// since it refers back to the original object
console.log(foo2)

// ..so we didn't copy, we just referred to it
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because happening because when you are pushing the object into the array, you are in fact pushing reference to the object.

```
arr.push(obj);
```

So when you change the any value within the object it changes only in one place, but the contents of your array in fact are referencing the same object. To avoid this you can do this to push the data to your array,

```
arr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
obj.x = i;
arr.push(obj);
```

do

```
var objCopy = Object.assign({}, obj, {x: i})
arr.push(objCopy);
```